# Contextual Help System in C# with all topics stored in one file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, html-helper, chm

I have a Form which consists of two panels, for simplicity.

One panel consists of, for example, several Controls.
The other panel displays Help text associated with each of these Controls.

When user clicks on each Control in the first panel, the other panel of the application will display some Help text (NOT a separate Help dialog window).

In reality I have many Controls; thence, many different topics. Therefore, ideally, I have a single file that contains all the help topics.

Please let me know how I might do it in C#, Winform.

---

I'd done lots of searches. I'd found something very close but it wasn't implemented in C#. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/281/Embedding-an-HTML-Help-window-into-a-dialog

Help Class or HelpProvider won't do the job as it launches the Help text in a separate dialog outside my application.

Could someone please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am oversimplifying or even misunderstanding what you are shooting for, but it sounds like you already have the solution (for the most part). Just put a label in the help panel that the other panel will update appropriately.

Pseudocode:

- item in main panel is clicked
- event method calls helpLabel.Text = "Help Stuff";

I am guessing I am misunderstanding this, though. Since you already have most of this.

Comment: Thanks Justin. I am afraid this is not what I am after. I need to provide a complete Help menu that might contain picture as well as text. The Help menu text shall only be displayed in a panel inside the application software; not to be outside in a Help dialog box.

Comment: Yes, panel would be inside the application. In no way did I say that this was going to be a help dialog box? Even the example you pointed to seemed to have a separate panel for the help information. That is what I am trying to explain. Or, are you trying to have more of a popup?

Comment: Sorry Justin, I confused you. I was only trying to explain that the Help Text should be displayed inside a panel as in the linked example. ie., Separate Help Dialog or Popup boxes are neither what I want.